# List of Acronyms is not in Sans Serif

Tags: acronyms, sans-serif

I am making a latex document using Tex Live and TexStudio.

I'm using acronym package and I do not know why, when I made the pdf file, the acronyms are not in Sans Serif. The code I'm using is like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{MRC}{Maximal Ratio Combining} \acro{QoS }{Quality of Service}
\acro{MIMO}{Multiple Input Multiple Output} \acro{RF }{Radio
 Frequency} \acro{TAS }{Transmit Antenna Selection}
\acro{VAA}{Virtual Antenna Array} \acro{ASER}{Average Symbol Error
Rate} \acrodef{SC}[SC]{Selection Combining} \acro{CSI }{Channel
State Information} \acro{AF  }{Amplify and Forward}
\acro{SNR}{Signal-to-Noise Ratio} \acro{CDF }{Cumulative
Distribution Function} \acro{PDF }{Probability Distribution
Function} \acro{MGF }{Moment Generating Function}
\acro{AWGN}{Additive White Gaussian Noise}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

I should get this:

[image]

Instead what I get is this:

[image]

I'm also trying use `lmodern` but it does not work.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you suppose that the acronyms **should** appear in sans-serif font automatically?

Comment: I use that before and this are working, then i tried use some packages like chemmacros and this stop working. I unistall texstudio and texlive and reinstall and this problem continues. I also tried use MikTex but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: The package was updated some months ago, perhaps this labelling changed then.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same class as previously? The list is a simple description list, and only with the KOMA-class you would get sans serif.

Comment: when i use the first peace of code that i post in this topic i always get the result in the first picture. so i did not need to use any other peace of code. 
I tried use that code that you gave me, but when i made the alignment but it maintains sans-serif but are not in bold.

Comment: @João1: Which alignment???

Comment: I can solve the problem with the acronyms. Can you help with the problem with the lmodern did not work in any class of document?

Comment: @João1: No, I can't because your question is totally unclear to me.

Comment: João1, there is a langauge barrier here i think. Good thing is, LaTeX code doesn't have barriers arising from language. Please try make your problem obvious by just posting code that reproduces your trouble, along with possible log-files. They should not be long for minimal examples.

Comment: @João1 Whatever problem you have with lmodern: "don't work" is not a sensible problem description. Also in my opinion you are either using a local version of acronym.sty or you didn't show your complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution, redefining `\aclabelfont` to use `\textsf{#1}` explicitly. This only works for the labels, but not for the full acronym expansion. (But as the screen shot in the OP does not show sans serif expanded texts, this doesn't seem to be an issue)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\renewcommand{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textsf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{MRC}{Maximal Ratio Combining} \acro{QoS }{Quality of Service}
\acro{MIMO}{Multiple Input Multiple Output} \acro{RF }{Radio
 Frequency} \acro{TAS }{Transmit Antenna Selection}
\acro{VAA}{Virtual Antenna Array} \acro{ASER}{Average Symbol Error
Rate} \acrodef{SC}[SC]{Selection Combining} \acro{CSI }{Channel
State Information} \acro{AF  }{Amplify and Forward}
\acro{SNR}{Signal-to-Noise Ratio} \acro{CDF }{Cumulative
Distribution Function} \acro{PDF }{Probability Distribution
Function} \acro{MGF }{Moment Generating Function}
\acro{AWGN}{Additive White Gaussian Noise}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works without `lmodern` too

Comment: Ok thank you very much.
When I am using     book and article Sans Serif normally appears automatically, but now only when i use     scrartcl Sans Serif appears.
Other strange thing is that lmodern stop working.

Comment: @João1: I don't understand. If I switch to `scrartcl` I still see sans serif, even without `lmodern`

Comment: Sorry i will try explain better. 
1º - When i try use lmodern it does not works. Not even in normal text.
2º - When you use `book` or `article` and you use `acronym` Sans Serif appears automatically or you need to add another piece of code?
For me it always appear sans serif withou anything else.

Comment: @João1: Neither `book` nor `article` use sf by default, so I have to activate `\aclabelfont` to that. **"For me it always appear sans serif withou anything else"** -- what's the question then, if it already appears sans serif? Totally unclear, I am sorry.